# How to get file name of logging.FileHandler in Python?

Tags: python, logging, file-io, python-logging

A `logging.FileHandler` is constructed with a file name, so is there any way to get the file name from the `logging.FileHandler` object?

I tried `dir(logging.FileHandler)` but didn't see any possible solutions.

Comment: http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Get-file-name-from-file-handle-td1540681.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
>>> import logging
>>> fh = logging.FileHandler('/Users/defuz/test.txt')
>>> fh.baseFilename
'/Users/defuz/test.txt'
>>> fh.stream.name
'/Users/defuz/test.txt'
```

Answer (score 6):

Please find dir(logging.FileHandler)

```py
 ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
  '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', 
  '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
  '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_name', '_open', 'acquire', 
  'addFilter', 'baseFilename', 'close', 'createLock', 'emit', 'encoding', 'filter', 
  'filters', 'flush', 'format', 'formatter', 'get_name', 'handle', 'handleError', 
  'level', 'lock', 'mode', 'name', 'release', 'removeFilter', 'setFormatter', 'setLevel', 
  'set_name', 'stream']
```

You have option obj.baseFilename to get the file name.